# openCv undistort using a 2 parameter distortion coefficient model

Tags: c++, opencv

I am attempting to undistort some pre recorded footage, where I no longer have access to the camera. It was recorded with a camera system that calibrated and stored the intrinsic data. So far so good.

BUT, although the values for creating the camera matrix are as expected, the distortion coefficient values are based on a 2 parameter model.

Therefore the data I have is:

camera matrix:

```
1141.04534668485,0,655.585107170347
0,1141.04534668485,359.721766081201
0, 0,1
```

distortion coeff: (from the calibration file)

RADIAL="2.58565363397419e-007 1.56049733948831e-013"

opencv undistort function needs a 1 x 5 matrix, it seems, so I am stuck. How can I create this from 2 values?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to give us more info. What do those parameters stand for? What are the other calibration params of the camera? With only two parameters, you need to have many more hypothesis in order to be able to fit the camera model. Two parameters barely fit a rigid translation. I presume that those parameters refer to radial distortion (https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/pomarc/pubs/BritoCVPR13.pdf). Perhaps they'd be sufficient assuming the center of distortion is the image center. Surely you don't have enough info to call `calibrateCamera`.

Comment: Hi, I have the 3x3 camera matrix also, which is fine. It is only the distortion coeff matrix that I need to figure out. Is there a way to make a 1x5 mat from those 2 values? I assume they are k1 and k2, but filling p1, p2 and k3 with zeros gives me an incorrect result.

Comment: `p1` and `p2` should be 0, as they refer to tangental distortion. It remains no other option but `k1` and `k2` (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html). Can you attach a frame before & after `undistort`? Anyway consider that your coefficients are practically 0, there is almost no radial correction at all there, and you probably need to work with double precision even to be able to see it.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought. You are right though, it gives me almost no change when i use the values. (The lens is almost fisheye, so there is a significant distortion).

Comment: The thing is that they're the coefficients of a polynomial in `r`, which is a function of `x` and `y`, so they can't even be the result of the evaluation of that polynomial. I would expect a fisheye lens to have a significant radial distortion, and being 0 the default value for the `k_i`s (meaning no distortion), those value do not make sense. Perhaps you may want to try to recalibrate it manually by mapping sets of points?